# Why is Postgres 9.6 using a sequential scan when an index would be more efficient

Tags: postgresql, optimization, psql

I have a function which is being used on our system. When you run the function direct on the server itself it takes milliseconds to run. However when it is run via the application it takes seconds (approx 5-7 seconds). Below is the query along with the output of the explain analyze for both examples.

Seq Scan Query

```
 SELECT c.card_id,
       p.payment_amount     AS amount,
       p.payment_created_on AS created_on
FROM   card c
join   payment p
USING  (card_id)
WHERE  c.card_id = _card_id
AND    c.customer_id = p.customer_id
AND    card_is_active = TRUE
AND    p.payment_state_id = 2
UNION
SELECT    c.card_id,
          w.withdrawal_amount     AS amount,
          w.withdrawal_created_on AS created_on
FROM      card c
join      withdrawal w
ON        w.withdrawal_preference ilike '%cardId='
                    || c.card_id
                    || ',%'
left join payment p
ON        (
                    p.withdrawal_id = w.withdrawal_id)
WHERE     c.card_id = _card_id
AND       card_is_active = TRUE
AND       c.customer_id = w.customer_id
AND       (
                    w.withdrawal_state_id = 1
          OR        (
                              w.withdrawal_state_id = 2
                    AND       (
                                        p IS NULL
                              OR        p.payment_state_id = 0
                              OR        p.payment_state_id = 1)))
UNION
SELECT    c.card_id,
          w.withdrawal_amount     AS amount,
          w.withdrawal_created_on AS created_on
FROM      card c
join      withdrawal w
ON        w.card_id = c.card_id
left join payment p
ON        (
                    p.withdrawal_id = w.withdrawal_id)
WHERE     c.card_id = _card_id
AND       card_is_active = TRUE
AND       c.customer_id = w.customer_id
AND       (
                    w.withdrawal_state_id = 1
          OR        (
                              w.withdrawal_state_id = 2
                    AND       (
                                        p IS NULL
                              OR        p.payment_state_id = 0
                              OR        p.payment_state_id = 1)))
GROUP BY  c.card_id,
          amount,
          created_on
ORDER BY  card_id,
          created_on;
```

Explain Result

```
Sort  (cost=2186725.49..2186725.50 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=10142.968..10142.972 rows=38 loops=1)
      Sort Key: c.card_id, p.payment_created_on
      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2186725.44..2186725.47 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=10142.922..10142.934 rows=38 loops=1)
            Group Key: c.card_id, p.payment_amount, p.payment_created_on
            ->  Append  (cost=0.86..2186725.41 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=1.948..10142.875 rows=39 loops=1)
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..8.91 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=1.947..2.390 rows=37 loops=1)
                        ->  Index Scan using card_pkey on card c  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.878..1.879 rows=1 loops=1)
                              Index Cond: (card_id = $1)
                              Filter: card_is_active
                        ->  Index Scan using idx_payment_customer_card_payment_state_id on payment p  (cost=0.43..4.46 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.063..0.496 rows=37 loops=1)
                              Index Cond: ((customer_id = c.customer_id) AND (card_id = $1) AND (payment_state_id = 2))
                  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=19.62..1093362.07 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=5201.374..5201.375 rows=1 loops=1)
                        Hash Cond: (p_1.withdrawal_id = w.withdrawal_id)
                        Filter: ((w.withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR ((w.withdrawal_state_id = 2) AND ((p_1.* IS NULL) OR (p_1.payment_state_id = 0) OR (p_1.payment_state_id = 1))))
                        ->  Seq Scan on payment p_1  (cost=0.00..1058836.58 rows=9201558 width=141) (actual time=2833.069..4727.364 rows=9267237 loops=1)
                        ->  Hash  (cost=19.61..19.61 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.133..0.133 rows=1 loops=1)
                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..19.61 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.076..0.130 rows=1 loops=1)
                                    ->  Index Scan using card_pkey on card c_1  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                                          Index Cond: (card_id = $1)
                                          Filter: card_is_active
                                    ->  Index Scan using withdrawal_idx_01 on withdrawal w  (cost=0.43..15.16 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=0.065..0.117 rows=1 loops=1)
                                          Index Cond: (customer_id = c_1.customer_id)
                                          Filter: (((withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR (withdrawal_state_id = 2)) AND ((withdrawal_preference)::text ~~* (('%cardId='::text || (c_1.card_id)::text) || ',%'::text)))
                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                  ->  Group  (cost=1093354.40..1093354.41 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=4939.100..4939.101 rows=1 loops=1)
                        Group Key: c_2.card_id, w_1.withdrawal_amount, w_1.withdrawal_created_on
                        ->  Sort  (cost=1093354.40..1093354.40 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=4939.096..4939.097 rows=1 loops=1)
                              Sort Key: w_1.withdrawal_amount, w_1.withdrawal_created_on
                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=11.94..1093354.39 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=4939.063..4939.065 rows=1 loops=1)
                                    Hash Cond: (p_2.withdrawal_id = w_1.withdrawal_id)
                                    Filter: ((w_1.withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR ((w_1.withdrawal_state_id = 2) AND ((p_2.* IS NULL) OR (p_2.payment_state_id = 0) OR (p_2.payment_state_id = 1))))
                                    ->  Seq Scan on payment p_2  (cost=0.00..1058836.58 rows=9201558 width=141) (actual time=2554.560..4496.499 rows=9267237 loops=1)
                                    ->  Hash  (cost=11.93..11.93 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.111..0.111 rows=1 loops=1)
                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.88..11.93 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.108..0.109 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                ->  Index Scan using card_pkey on card c_2  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                      Index Cond: (card_id = $1)
                                                      Filter: card_is_active
                                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on withdrawal w_1  (cost=5.46..7.48 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.076..0.076 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                      Recheck Cond: ((card_id = $1) AND (customer_id = c_2.customer_id))
                                                      Filter: ((withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR (withdrawal_state_id = 2))
                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                                                      Heap Blocks: exact=10
                                                      ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=5.46..5.46 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_withdrawal_card_id  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=22 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=10 loops=1)
                                                                  Index Cond: (card_id = $1)
                                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on withdrawal_idx_01  (cost=0.00..2.62 rows=25 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=10 loops=1)
                                                                  Index Cond: (customer_id = c_2.customer_id)
```

Query explain which runs quicker but doesnt the seq scan

```
Sort  (cost=587100.95..587100.96 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=1.266..1.267 rows=8 loops=1)
  Sort Key: c.card_id, p.payment_created_on
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=587100.90..587100.93 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=1.206..1.206 rows=8 loops=1)
        Group Key: c.card_id, p.payment_amount, p.payment_created_on
        ->  Append  (cost=0.86..587100.88 rows=3 width=44) (actual time=0.276..1.191 rows=8 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..8.91 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.276..0.348 rows=8 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_card_id_card_is_active_true on card c  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.047..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (card_id = 876742)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_payment_customer_card_payment_state_id on payment p  (cost=0.43..4.46 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.225..0.294 rows=8 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((customer_id = c.customer_id) AND (card_id = 876742) AND (payment_state_id = 2))
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=19.41..293549.69 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.694..0.694 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (p_1.withdrawal_id = w.withdrawal_id)
                    Filter: ((w.withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR ((w.withdrawal_state_id = 2) AND ((p_1.* IS NULL) OR (p_1.payment_state_id = 0) OR (p_1.payment_state_id = 1))))
                    ->  Seq Scan on payment p_1  (cost=0.00..258737.01 rows=9278201 width=142) (never executed)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=19.40..19.40 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.675..0.675 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..19.40 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.675..0.675 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Scan using idx_card_id_card_is_active_true on card c_1  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (card_id = 876742)
                                ->  Index Scan using withdrawal_idx_01 on withdrawal w  (cost=0.43..14.94 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=0.668..0.668 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (customer_id = c_1.customer_id)
                                      Filter: (((withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR (withdrawal_state_id = 2)) AND ((withdrawal_preference)::text ~~* (('%cardId='::text || (c_1.card_id)::text) || ',%'::text)))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2
              ->  Group  (cost=293542.23..293542.24 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.148..0.148 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Group Key: c_2.card_id, w_1.withdrawal_amount, w_1.withdrawal_created_on
                    ->  Sort  (cost=293542.23..293542.23 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.148..0.148 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: w_1.withdrawal_amount, w_1.withdrawal_created_on
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=11.94..293542.22 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.106..0.106 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (p_2.withdrawal_id = w_1.withdrawal_id)
                                Filter: ((w_1.withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR ((w_1.withdrawal_state_id = 2) AND ((p_2.* IS NULL) OR (p_2.payment_state_id = 0) OR (p_2.payment_state_id = 1))))
                                ->  Seq Scan on payment p_2  (cost=0.00..258737.01 rows=9278201 width=142) (never executed)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=11.92..11.92 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.88..11.92 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            ->  Index Scan using idx_card_id_card_is_active_true on card c_2  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (card_id = 876742)
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on withdrawal w_1  (cost=5.45..7.47 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.081..0.081 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ((card_id = 876742) AND (customer_id = c_2.customer_id))
                                                  Filter: ((withdrawal_state_id = 1) OR (withdrawal_state_id = 2))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=2
                                                  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=5.45..5.45 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.070..0.070 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_withdrawal_card_id  (cost=0.00..2.59 rows=21 width=0) (actual time=0.058..0.058 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                              Index Cond: (card_id = 876742)
                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on withdrawal_idx_01  (cost=0.00..2.62 rows=25 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                              Index Cond: (customer_id = c_2.customer_id)
Planning time: 8.427 ms
Execution time: 1.621 ms
```

I can see the sequential scan is what is the cause but cannot find a workaround. As said before the tables are small (totalling 2GB)

```
select count (*) from withdrawal;
  count  
---------
 1775187
(1 row)

select count (*) from payment;
  count  
---------
 9285654
(1 row)

select count (*) from card;
 count  
--------
 879479
(1 row)
```

I have looked into the option of setting enable_seqscan = off but that would have a global effect on the system.

Postgres config:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 1000
hot_standby = on
shared_buffers = 20GB
temp_buffers = 30MB
max_prepared_transactions = 1000
work_mem = 250MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
effective_io_concurrency = 4
effective_cache_size = 50GB
```

We are looking to upgrade in the near future as PG 9.6 is out of support and see that in newer features 10 and above can create statistics which may help.

Trying to figure out why postgres is behaving like this, understand that postgres uses sequential scans if row count returned is > than a certain amount but in this case it doesnt look like its as efficient as not doing the sequential scan.

Could an index force postgres to not do the seq scan?

Any help is much appreciated.

Updated to include the tables in question.

```
                                            Table "public.payment"
       Column        |           Type           |                          Modifiers                           
---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 payment_id          | integer                  | not null default nextval('payment_payment_id_seq'::regclass)
 customer_id         | integer                  | not null
 payment_method_id   | integer                  | not null
 payment_created_on  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 payment_amount      | numeric(20,2)            | not null
 payment_reverse_id  | integer                  | 
 withdrawal_id       | integer                  | 
 payment_state_id    | integer                  | not null
 payment_description | character varying(100)   | 
 card_id             | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "payment_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (payment_id)
    "idx_payment_customer_card_payment_state_id" btree (customer_id, card_id, payment_state_id)
    "payment_idx_01" btree (customer_id)
    "payment_idx_02" btree (payment_reference)
    "payment_idx_03" btree (payment_created_on)
```

```
                                            Table "public.card"
        Column         |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        
-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 card_id               | integer                  | not null default nextval('card_card_id_seq'::regclass)
 customer_id           | integer                  | not null
 card_security_token   | character varying(100)   | 
 card_is_active        | boolean                  | not null default true
 payment_method_id     | integer                  | not null

 card_last_updated_on  | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "card_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (card_id)
    "card_idx_01" btree (customer_id)
    "idx_card_id_card_is_active" btree (card_id, card_is_active)
    "idx_card_id_card_is_active_true" btree (card_id) WHERE card_is_active = true
```

```
                                                   Table "public.withdrawal"
             Column             |           Type           |                             Modifiers                              
--------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 withdrawal_id                  | integer                  | not null default nextval('withdrawal_withdrawal_id_seq'::regclass)
 customer_id                    | integer                  | not null
 currency_code                  | character(3)             | not null
 withdrawal_amount              | numeric(10,2)            | not null
 withdrawal_created_on          | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 withdrawal_state_id            | integer                  | not null
 withdrawal_preference          | character varying(255)   | 
 withdrawal_decline_reason_id   | integer                  | 
 card_id                        | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "withdrawal_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (withdrawal_id)
    "idx_withdrawal_card_id" btree (card_id)
    "idx_withdrawal_id" btree (withdrawal_id)
    "idx_withdrawal_withdrawal_created_on" btree (withdrawal_created_on)
    "withdrawal_idx_01" btree (customer_id)
```

Comment: Please add the tables' `CREATE TABLE` statements including indexes (or the output of `\d tablename`. What indexes there are on the tables can seriously affect the plans.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ updated.

Comment: Those plans aren't for the same query and parameters.  They return different numbers of rows.

Comment: Those plans both have 2 seq scans planned.  In one case, they don't actually get run because their sibling nodes returned zero rows, so they were not needed.  That is an accident of the data being returned by the query, and something discovered at run time.  It is not something that can be planned for.

Comment: @jjanes apologies yes you are correct, copied the wrong plan! I did realise that there was an index that when added to payment (withdrawal_id) it vastly improved the query.